# Graph Isomorphism: Polynomial time reduction from GI for disconnected graphs to GI for connected graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, reductions, graph-isomorphism

Let the *Graph Isomorphism Problem* be the problem to decide whether there is a one-to-one mapping between the vertices of two graphs that preserves the edge relations.

Let the *Graph Isomorphism Problem for Connected Graphs* be the problem to decide whether there is a one-to-one mapping between the vertices of two connected graphs that preserves the edge relations.

Is there a polynomial time reduction from the Graph Isomorphism Problem to the Graph Isomorphism Problem for connected graphs? How can I prove it?

Comment: This is not a research-level question so is [off-topic](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), here. [Computer Science Stack Exchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com) would have been a more appropriate place to ask but, since the question has already been answered, there's no need to repost there.

Comment: Sorry. The research-level criterion for questions should be put into the "How to ask" box on the ask page to avoid this from happening.

Comment: Good point. I've [suggested it on meta](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2739/mentioning-research-level-in-how-to-ask).

Comment: The "research-level" requirement is now mentioned both in the "How to ask" box and the greyed out text that sits in the subject line before it's edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the following simple reduction: given graphs $G$ and $H$, 
let $G' = G * g$ and $H' = H * h$, where $X * x$ is obtained from $X$ by adding a new 
vertex $x$ and all edges between $x$ and all vertices in $X$ 
(so, $x$ is universal in $X * x$).

Then $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic iff $G'$ and $H'$ are isomorphic. 
Note that, in all cases, $G'$ and $H'$ are connected.

Comment: Your reduction doesn't require that $G$ and $H$ have no universal vertex (which is good, since you can't actually assume that).

Comment: Oh, yes, you are right.

Comment: We don't answer undergraduate homework level questions on this site.